# 2D CAD application for Ubuntu 14.04 ---> output DWG/DXF files

Tags: 14.04, cad, 2d

I would like to know if there are any 2D/3D CAD software available for Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm looking for software that produces DWG/DXF files.

Answer (score 3):

There are lot of apps to use. check this [UbuntuEngineering](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering).

But as a first choice I advise you to use [FreeCAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/).

Quoted from official site:

> FreeCAD is a parametric 3D modeler made primarily to design real-life
>   objects of any size. Parametric modeling allows you to easily modify
>   your design by going back into your model history and changing its
>   parameters. FreeCAD is open-source and highly customizable, scriptable
>   and extensible.
>
> FreeCAD is multiplatfom (Windows, Mac and Linux), and reads and writes
>   many open file formats such as STEP, IGES, STL, SVG, DXF, OBJ, IFC,
>   DAE and many others.

You can install it using command line:

```
sudo apt-get install freecad
```

Answer (score 2):

Try LibreCAD, here is [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreCAD)

It supports DXF by libdxfrw.

Answer (score -1):

I use [DraftSight](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/) on Kubuntu 15.10. Works well and is similiar in layout to AutoCad. Dwg/Dxf supported.

Comment: It seems there's no Linux version anymore - just windows and Mac.